# Decimal Formatting for Multiple Parameters at once

Tags: c#, string, decimal, string-formatting

The following line has results similar to: `5.67`, `7.89`, `491`, `23`, etc.

```
string message=string.Format("{0:0.00}", x_);//WORKS BECAUSE IT IS DOCUMENTED
```

I wanted to two values after decimal point, as I am normally getting. This only works when the formatted string has only **one** parameter.

When I wanted to format multiple decimals, I tried two options:

```
string message=string.Format("x:{0:0.00} y:{1:0.00}", x_, y_);
string message=string.Format("x:{0:0.00} y:{1:1.11}", x_, y_);
```

I want to get a string similar to this

```
 x:167.34 y:4.12  // float x=167.33586973; float y=4.12252752
 x:592.78 y:5.89  // float x=592.78473721; float y=5.8879221
```

---

My temporay solution is this:

```
string tmpx = string.Format("x:{0:0.00}", x_);
string tmpy = string.Format("y:{0:0.00}", y_);
string message = string.Format("x:{0} y:{1}", tmpx, tmpy);
```

But I'm looking for a single line `string.Format` solution.

Comment: What exact error does it show?

Comment: your first "Not working" example formats correctly on my machine

Comment: The first attempt looks like it should work, what is the output?

Comment: `x:{0:0.00} y:{1:0.00}` should give you the correct output, however you could also do `x:{0:N2} y{1:N2}`

Comment: So far your question can't be answered due to lack of "I'm getting XXXXX instead of YYYYYY}. Side note: `y:{1:1.11}` is very strange format.

Comment: yes, the first line is working. It was late nite that I couldnt detect.thus, there is no similar question asked before. so I decided not to delete and archieved. maybe help someone too.